# Excel is copying all data even if the Autofilter criteria matches no data entry

Tags: xml, vba, autofilter

Good afternoon everyone,

I am new here and only have reasonable knowledge about VBA, so please excuse if my terminology may not be right.

I have an excel file with several macros I have written. The main macro applies an autofilter to all my data based on a criteria I type in a cell on a separate sheet within the same workbook. The filter is working fine and if the criteria specified matches a record in my data then that data is copied and pasted into a separate sheet.
Unfortunately, however, if I enter a criteria that is not present in the data, excel/VBA copies all of my data (each of the 7000 records) and pastes the entire data into the separate sheet although no result was actually found. I was hoping you would be able to give me advice on how to overcoem this and what code to use to make the filter work properly.

Basically what I want is that if the filter cannot match any data, then no data is copied/pasted. My macro checks several criteria (total 8) and then applies the autofilter. I don't know if I would need a code and add that to each of my code lines for each criteria, or only one at the end.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would check if the filter produced any results/rows by comparing the number of rows in the table to the number of rows in the filtered table.

```
'assuming the table starts from A1,
MsgBox Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
'confirms the number of rows in the table.
'After trying AutoFilter,
MsgBox ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
'confirms the number of filtered rows.
```

Store these two values in variables and compare them, or just check if the second value is 1 (the header row). If it is one, don't attempt the Copy.